# How to add a sub-directory to a git repository given, this sub-directory used to be a repository itself but it has been deleted?

Tags: git, git-submodules

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRpC.png)

[image]

Please check the image above for clarity. 
Even though Repo3 doesn’t exist, when I am trying to add it to Repo2, it is giving some sub-module error and creating this directory inside repo2, but It appears grey and I cannot get inside it.
So, I went inside, Repo2 and used the following command – 
*git submodule add https://github.com/GitRepo/Repo3*    -  though Repo3 doesn’t exist.
After the above command, I can see a directory Repo3 @(some random number) is created inside Repo2 but when I am clicking on it, it is taking me to an error page stating that the webpage that I am looking for doesn’t exist.
So what should I do now?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "_it is giving some submodule error_"? What's the error message? Also, how did you go about deleting `Repo3`?